# Using HTTP in NativeScript to send Post-data to a TYPO3-Webservice

Tags: javascript, nativescript, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to send form data from a NativeScript app to a TYPO3-Webservice.

This is the JavaScript I'm using:

```
httpModule.request({
            url: "https://my.domain.tld/webservice?action=login",
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            content: JSON.stringify({
                username:username,
                password:password
            })
        }).then((response) => {
             console.log("got response");
             console.log(response.content);
            //result = response.content.toJSON();
            callback(response.content.toJSON());

        }, (e) => {

            console.log("error");
            console.log(e);

        });
```

But I can't read this data in the controller. Even with this:

```
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postvars = json_decode($rest_json, true);
```

`$postvars` is empty. `$_POST` is empty, too (which is - according to some docs - because the data is sent as JSON and thus the `$_POST`-Array isn't populated.

Whatever I do, whatever I try, I can't get those variables into my controller.

I tried it with `fetch` as well as with `formData` instead of `JSON.stringify`, same result.

I might have to add, that when I add the PHP-part in the index.php of TYPO3, `$postvars` is being populated. So I guess something goes missing, until the controller is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the nativescript part seems ok, your problem must be corrected in the server side.

i use similare call and its works

```
// send POST request
httpModule.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: appSettings.getString("SERVER") + '/product/list',
    content: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    timeout: 5000,
}).then(response => { // handle replay
    const responseAsJson = response.content.toJSON();
    console.log('dispatchAsync\n\tresponse:', responseAsJson);
}, reason => {
    console.error(`[ERROR] httpModule, msg: ${reason.message}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What server side code do you use? What framework?